# php - xml. Is it possible to access particular xml node without looping through all data of xml file

Tags: php, xml, xpath, simplexml

Xml file like this

```
<xml>

<Categories>
<OneSubcategory>

<Id>4</Id>
<CategoriesUrl>cars</CategoriesUrl>

<Id>5</Id>
<CategoriesUrl>staff-required</CategoriesUrl>

</OneSubcategory>
</Categories>

</xml>
```

Want to get value of `<Id>` where `<CategoriesUrl>` is `cars`

Now i do this

1) `$xml = simplexml_load_file( filename.xml' );`

2) then loop through all file

```
foreach($xml->children() as $subcategory){
  if( trim($subcategory->OneSubcategory->CategoriesUrl) == 'cars' ){
  $id = trim($subcategory->OneSubcategory->Id);
  }
}
```

Is it possible to get the value without looping, like mysql `SELECT Id WHERE CategoriesUrl = 'cars'`?

**Update**

Based on this http://www.tuxradar.com/practicalphp/12/3/3#null

With `$id = $xml->xpath('Categories/OneSubcategory/Id');` get array of all `Id`

Tried `$id = $xml->xpath('Categories/OneSubcategory/Id[CategoriesUrl="cars"]');`
Get empty array

What is incorrect?

**Seems this is a solution**

`$id = $xml->xpath('Categories/OneSubcategory[CategoriesUrl="cars"]/Id');`

Comment: You can use xPath requests. Google it

Comment: you can use [xpath queries](http://php.net/manual/en/simplexmlelement.xpath.php).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The query seems off since `CategoriesUrl` and `Id` are siblings. If you do not want to loop then just explicitly set the index to zero to get the first value.

```
$query = "//Id[following-sibling::CategoriesUrl[text() = 'cars']]";
$nodes = $xml->xpath($query);
if(count($nodes) > 0) { // if found
    // get one
    $id = $nodes[0];
    echo $id;

    // if you want to loop
    // foreach($nodes as $node) { // loop all results
    //  $id = (string) $node;
    //  echo $id;
    // }
}
```

If you want all results found, then just use foreach.

Comment: All works, thanks! `Id[following-sibling::CategoriesUrl[text() = 'cars']` means: get Id inside node where text of CategoriesUrl of the same node equals to cars?

Comment: @user2118559 it simply means get all the nodes with the name `Id` which has a following sibling of `CategoriesUrl` with a text `cars`. Glad this helped